# Symfony voter via subresource is not being called

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, subresource-integrity, symfony2-voter

Here is the context :

I use Symfony 3.4 with api-platform.

I have two class :

- Supplier
- Product

I want to list all the supplier's product

In the Supplier Entity I have implemented access_control on regular CRUD method that works fine with the voter.

I also have a route through a subresource that does not work fine :

```
 * collectionOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('LIST', object)",
 *              "normalization_context"={"groups"={"supplier.liste"}},
 *          },
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "get"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('VIEW', object)",
 *          },
 *     },
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *          "supplier_product_get"={
 *              "path"="/supplier/{id}/products",
 *              "method"= "GET",
 *              "access_control"="is_granted('LIST', object)",
 *          },
 * }
```

The issue is, the access control for the subressource does not work. There it's supposed to go check the voter for permission on this resource but does not check the voter and return a HTTP response code 200 when I need him to return a 403.

I've checked the docs where they use security instead of access_control as such :

```
 * subresourceOperations={
 *          "supplier_product_get"={
 *              "path"="/supplier/{id}/products",
 *              "method"= "GET",
 *              "security"="is_granted('LIST', object)",
 *          },
 * }
```

And it doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any clue or tips on why the voter isn't called?

Answer (score 0):

Just one tip. I think that the operation **has** to be named something like "api_questions_answer_get_subresource", in your case "api_products_supplier_get_subresource" (check the name with "bin/console debug:router").
See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/#subresources
"*Note that the operation name, here api_questions_answer_get_subresource, is the important keyword. It'll be automatically set to $resources_$subresource(s)_get_subresource. To find the correct operation name you may use bin/console debug:router.*"
Also, it seems that you can use the 'object' parameter in the is_granted, and it contains the collection of the subresources (in my case, ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator). So if you intend to grant on your subresource's class, or the objects themselves, I think you're gonna need some extra work (just consider if you really need it).